# Problems discovering glibc version in C++

Tags: c++, linux, glibc

My application is distributed with two binaries. One which is linked to an old glibc (for example, 2.17) and another binary that targets a newer glibc (for example, 2.34). I also distribute a launcher binary (linked against glibc 2.17) which interrogates the user's libc version and then runs the correct binary.

My code to establish the user's libc looks something like the following:

```
std::string gnu(gnu_get_libc_version());
double g_ver = std::stod(gnu);
if(g_ver >= 2.34)
{
     return GLIBC_MAIN;
}
else
{
     return GLIBC_COMPAT;
}
```

This works perfectly for the best part, however, some of my users report that despite having a new glibc, the old glibc binary is actually run. I have investigated this and have discovered that *double g_ver* is equal to 2, not 2.34 as it should be. That is, the decimal part is missing. *gnu_get_libc_version()* always has the correct value so it must be a problem when converting the string to a double.

I have also tried boost::lexical_cast but this has the same effect.

```
std::string gnu(gnu_get_libc_version());
//double g_ver = std::stod(gnu);
double glibc = boost::lexical_cast<double>(gnu);
if(g_ver >= 2.34)
{
  return GLIBC_MAIN;
}
else
{
   return GLIBC_COMPAT;
}
```

Needless to say, I am unable to reproduce this behaviour on any of my computers even when running the exact same distribution / version of Linux as affected users.

Does anybody know why boost::lexical_cast or std::stod sometimes misses the decimal part of the version number? Is there an alternative approach to this?

**UPDATE**

Upon further tests, this problem is introduced when using a different locale. I set my locale to fr_FR.UTF-8 on a test machine and was able to reproduce this problem. However, the output of gnu_get_libc_version() seems to be correct but std::stod is unable to parse the decimal point part of the version.

Does anybody know how to correct this problem?

Comment: Note that version strings are not numbers, and should not be compared as numbers.  For example, **version** 2.34 is more recent than version 2.4, but the **number** 2.34 is less than the number 2.4.  Also, version strings sometimes have more than two components, in which case a naive conversion to a floating-point number just won't work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good point, I had not considered that. My deb installers only install on glibc 2.17 and higher. I need to rethink this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that the glibc version is a string and not a decimal number. So for a "proper" solution you need to parse it manually and implement your own logic to decide which version is bigger or smaller.

However, as a quick and dirty hack, try inserting the line

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
```

before the `strtod` call. That will set the numeric locale back to the default C locale where the decimal separator is `.`. If you're doing something that needs correct locales later in the program you need to set it back again. Depending on how your program initialized locales earlier, something like

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");
```

should reset it back to what the environment says the locale should be.

Comment: setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C"); works. How do I set it back to the users default after making the glibc check?

Comment: @Amanda: That depends on how you setup the locales in the first place; the default is the C locale so somewhere in your program you have previously called setlocale(). But since it uses the environment, I'd guess something like setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, ""); would reset it back to the environment settings.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. I've had confirmed reports that all is well in the "wild" now.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be the locale of the user?
The decimal separator is not a '.' in all locales and stod uses the current locale?

Comment: Not in any of the cases that I have seen. In every case so far,  std::string gnu(gnu_get_libc_version()); has had a standard decimal point, ie: 2.34.

Comment: UPDATE: I have just changed my locale to fr_FR.UTF-8 and have reproduced the problem. I will update my question.

Comment: Yes, @Amanda.  The point is not that the output of `gnu_get_libc_version()` may vary with locale, but rather that it *doesn't*, whereas the behavior of `std::stod()` *does*.

Answer (score 2):

As you are depending on glibc anyway, you can use [strverscmp](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String_002fArray-Comparison.html#index-strverscmp).

Answer (score 0):

gnu_get_libc_version() may return more than just X.X, It may be be 2.0.1 for example.

However strtod wont handle all of the invalid part of the number to would equate to 2.0 in this case.

You need to verify the actual value as a string returned from gnu_get_libc_version in the versions you currently do not have access to

Comment: I have already verified this, in every case that I have seen, gnu_get_libc_version() is returning a single decimal point. For example, 2.34